# Capacitor Stacking Charge Pump

Tags: voltage, transistors, capacitor

I have an infrared LED that needs a voltage drop of ~1.55V as well as a BJT to sink the current when the LED is in operation. That give me a total voltage drop needed of ~2.2V and unfortunately I have only got a 2V supply.
I have been told that there is such thing as capacitor stacking and it essentially charges two capacitors in parallel to the supply voltage (2V) and then discharges them in series which gives it twice the potential. However, firstly I am not even sure if that statement is correct, and secondly I wanted someone to explain to me how this actually happens?
I have a circuit diagram that I believe to do the correct thing but still am not sure as to what is going on with it:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpw1zL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So the way I understand it, given enough time, the capictors will charge to full capacity (2V) and then once the discharge trigger is made high cause a current to be present at the base of the PNP (Q1)  and this will allow current to flow through that transistor.
I don't understand how both can discharge to make twice the voltage... Any help in clarifying this with possible help from a diagram would be great.

Comment: Simpler to reduce the BJT voltage drop to 0.1 or 0.2V  aka saturate it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond There is a fairly large voltage drop over the emitter resistors due to the current being drawn (~1V)

Comment: As Brian says-- You can make a current sink with a 50mV or 100mV minimum drop using a smaller resistor value and a MOSFET .. As a bonus it will draw half the current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The basic rule is you can't instantly change the voltage across a capacitor.**

Q1 is a switch operated by an input to Q2 so redraw the circuit using a (controlled) switch which makes it easier to see what's happening.

[image]

When the circuit is powered up C1 an C2 charge up to about 2V. C2 will take longer to charge than C1 because it has R1,R2 and R5 reducing its charging current. After charging there is no current through R5 so there is no voltage difference between its ends. i.e. we now have 0V at the end of both capacitors and +2V at their positive ends. (initial charging circuit)

When Q1,Q2 is turned on the top end of R5 immediately jumps to +2V (held there by the voltage on C1).

Following the rule that **we cannot immediately change the voltage across a capacitor** then we must still have 2V across C2. This means that the positive end of C2 must be immediately raised to +4V because the other terminal is at +2V.

**N.B.** the rule **does not say** we can't instantly change the voltage at the capacitors terminals only that the voltage difference between them cannot change immediately. The rule is a consequence of the principle of charge conservation.

Neither capacitor has been discharged at this point (charge has been conserved) but we have effectively doubled the voltage at the output.

Answer (score 3):

If you took 2 capacitors and held each to the terminals of a battery, each would contain a charge with a voltage across each equal to the battery voltage. Assuming these capacitors don't leak, you could then connect them in series (just like 2 batteries), and the voltage across the pair would be twice battery voltage - and would light a LED if connected to it.

Redraw the circuit without R3, R4, Q2. Replace Q1 with a push-button switch. Over a period of time both capacitors charge fully through the resistors R1, R2, R5. The resistors have high values, so over a short time (when you press the button) will draw so little current as to have no effect on the capacitor charges. Then C1 (2V) is in series with C2 (2V) across the load.

You can minimise the circuit even further : remove R2 (connect the 2V supply directly to the switch), and C1. 
Now when you press the button the battery and the charged C2 are in series across the load, which sees (briefly) 4V.

That is the basis of charge-pump circuits used to produce an output that is higher in voltage than the DC supply.

Comment: @Sphex, you seem to have two unregistered accounts. While it's not mandatory you might want to consider registering using an Open ID provider like Google (or SE have one too) and then requesting an account merge using the "contact us" link towards the bottom of the page.